# Combine [NgStyle] With Condition (if..else)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have read [NgStyle Documentation For Angular 2](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle), and it is a little bit confusing for me. How do I use NgStyle with condition like (if...else) to set background image of any element?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using a ternary operator inside the `ngStyle` binding will function as an if/else condition.

```ts
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + value ? image : otherImage + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 137):

One can also use this kind of condition:

```
<div [ngStyle]="myBooleanVar && {'color': 'red'}"></div>
```

It requires a bit less string concatenation...

Comment: This is by far most useful example, because it sets the style if condition is met and leaves it untouched otherwise.

Comment: how do we use this "if" in addition to a style that uses a real "if else" like Gunter's answer, all in the same ngStyle? can't make a new div easily but need to do this

Comment: @assassinatorr I discovered you can also do this with the ? and : if you use ': null' or '? null'. This is useful if you would like to specify an if else in addition to just an 'if" in the same line.

Comment: It seems this won't work with TS, strict typing and Angular 14 anymore (haven't tested earlier versions though). You'll get `Type 'false | { color: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [klass: string]: any; } | null'.`. So ternary with `null` is like the alternative now.

Comment: Sadly you are right @insertusernamehere

Comment: What still should work however is this: `booleanVar && {color: 'red'} || null`.

Answer (score 34):

The previous answers did not work for me, so I decided to improve this.

You should work with `url('')`, and not with value.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div
    class="img-wrapper"
    [ngStyle]="{'background-image': !item.featured ? 'url(\'images/img1.png\')' : 'url(\'images/img2.png\')'}">
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use this as follows:

```
<div [style.background-image]="value ? 'url(' + imgLink + ')' : 'url(' + defaultLink + ')'"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

**[ngStyle]** with condition based if and else case.

```
<label for="file" [ngStyle]="isPreview ? {'cursor': 'default'} : {'cursor': 'pointer'}">Attachment</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add and simplify Günter Zöchbauer's the example incase using (if...else) to set something else than background image :

```
<p [ngStyle]="value == 10 && { 'font-weight': 'bold' }">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<h2 [ngStyle]="serverStatus == 'Offline'? {'color': 'red'{'color':'green'}">Server with ID: {{serverId}} is {{getServerStatus()}} </h2>
```

or you can also use something like this:

```
<h2 [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: getColor()}">Server with ID: {{serverId}} is {{getServerStatus()}}</h2>
```

and in the *.ts

```
getColor(){return this.serverStatus === 'Offline' ? 'red' : 'green';}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have used the below code in my existing project

```
<div class="form-group" [ngStyle]="{'border':isSubmitted && form_data.controls.first_name.errors?'1px solid red':'' }">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Trying to set background color based on condition:   

Consider variable x with some numeric value.    
<p [ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor: x > 4 ? 'lightblue' : 'transparent' }">
        This is a sample Text
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in a "let element" case where 'devices' is my variable of type number.

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': (element.devices >= 31.5) ? ('green') : (element.devices === 23.5) ? ('gold') : ('red')}"
```

this has two conditionals where if devices >= 31.5 will be green and if it's not true then evaluate the second condition that is devices === 23.5 will be gold and if this is false too, then goes red color. You can add more than one conditional like that but you need to finish with an "else" or with a default element.

Answer (score 1):

Today I discovered how to use `else if` with ngStyle, allowing as many conditions as you want:

```
 [ngStyle]="(myCondition1 === 'hello' && {'background-color': 'purple'}) 
 
 || (myCondition1 === 'world' && {'background-color': 'orange'}) 

 || (myCondition1 === 'fubar' && {'background-color': 'red'})"
```

Note: the "&&" here might make more sense if it was a "->" but that's just how the syntax is I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' +1=1 ? ../../assets/img/emp-user.png : ../../assets/img/emp-default.jpg + ')'}"
```