# How to use ternary operator in ngStyle

Tags: angular, angular8

I am getting `profileImage` object in which sometime data(`profileImage.url`) is present and sometimes not(null). How can i write turnary operator in `ngStyle` so that if `profileImage.url` is present then show it, other wise `user.image` (in which common image url is present)

this is i tried

```html
<div class="image-avatar"
  [ngStyle]="{
      'background-image': 'url(' + user.profileImage && user.profileImage.url ? user.profileImage.url : user.image + ')'
    }">
</div>
```

and i am getting error `Cannot read property 'url' of null`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/37051581/9880356

Comment: @Giannis i also written in same way... what i did wrong?

Comment: nothing really looks wrong here, makes me think the error is actually occurring somewhere else... but you should just be able to write `'url(' + user.profileImage?.url || user.image + ')'`

Comment: @bryan60 only left side is working. but when profileImage is null, then its not working for user.image

Comment: can't speak to why it's not working. maybe something wrong with that property. can't know without seeing the object

Comment: I agree this looks fine. That said, `&& user.profileImage.url != null ` should work. Even better though, I'd place this in the component typescript as a function.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by

```
<div class="image-avatar" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': user.profileImage && user.profileImage.url ? 'url('+user.profileImage.url+')' : 'url('+user.image+')'}">
```